# Type hinting on __aenter__ with generic inheritance is broken in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have this simple example of a Generic class with a `__aenter__`:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


class A(Generic[T]):
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self


class B(A[int]):
    def b(self): pass


async with B() as b:
    b.b
```

For some reasons PyCharm doesn't show `b()` as an available function
[image: With generics]

But when I remove generics from classes:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


class A:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self


class B(A):
    def b(self): pass


async with B() as b:
    b.b()
```

I get `b()` available

[image: Without generics]

What's wrong? And is the only way to bypass it - overriding `__aenter__` for every subclass?

PyCharm 2021.3

Comment: I would appreciate if someone tests it in VS Code and shares results

Comment: On my VS Code env, I get the `b()` function in the autocomplete/intellisense list with _both_ the 1st case with the Generics, and the 2nd case without the Generics. Not sure if relevant, but using Python 3.9.10 and mypy 0.940.